# How to use div element to show google maps?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, html

I am learning the basics of Google Maps API.
But I am facing some issues in implementing it into my template.

I use

```
<div class=container>
  <!-- I put it here --> <div id='canvas'></div> <!-- It doesn't work -->
</div>
```

But I put

```
<!--I put it here, it's work --> <div id='canvas'></div >
<div class=container>
</div>
```

How should I do it?

Comment: may be problem with class. try changing the class container.

Comment: Well classes are wrapped by `'`  or `""`! Is that your actual code?

Comment: we need to see your CSS

Comment: Specify a width and height of the container, otherwise its probably about 0x0px large.

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the class:

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- I put it here --> <div id='canvas'></div> <!-- It doesn't work -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add style="width:100%; height:100%;" to the div and see what that does. Do not forget to quote the classname.

like this:

```
<div class='container' style="height:100%; width:100%;">
    <div id='canvas'></div> 
</div>
```